# Adding StyleSheets Programmatically in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I want to add StyleSheets programmatically in the head section but one of the examples I saw seemed to need to many lines of code to add just one style sheet even though I may need a lot:

**Example Code:**

```
HtmlLink css = new HtmlLink();
css.Href = "css/fancyforms.css";
css.Attributes["rel"] = "stylesheet";
css.Attributes["type"] = "text/css";
css.Attributes["media"] = "all";
Page.Header.Controls.Add(css);
```

I also use `Page.Header.RenderControl()` method but it didn't work either. Object null something error was thrown.

I also used `Page.Header.InnerHtml` and `InnerText += "<link .... "/>` things but they threw  the Literal error which is I think common error.

I used this code :

```
List<Literal> cssFiles = new List<Literal>();
cssFiles.Add(new Literal() { Text = @"<link href=""" +   ResolveUrl("~/Resources/Styles/MainMaster/MainDesign.css") + @""" type=""text/css"" rel=""stylesheet"" />" });
cssFiles.Add(new Literal() { Text = @"<link href=""" + ResolveUrl("~/Resources/Styles/MainMaster/MainLayout.css") + @""" type=""text/css"" rel=""stylesheet"" />" });
AddStyleRange(cssFiles);

private void AddStyleRange(List<Literal> cssFiles)
{
   foreach (Literal item in cssFiles)
   {
     this.Header.Controls.Add(item);
   }
}
```

It worked at first but when I change the pages it stopped working.

I am using Master Page and I am writing these codes on `Master.cs` file and also some people recommended to use `this.Header` instead of `Page.Header` but when I built it throws an error which says I cannot declare that like this.

It shouldn't be that hard to add many styles.

It is getting complicated.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Okay, here is the solution I am currently using :

**I created a helper class :**

```
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace BusinessLogic.Helper
{
    public class CssAdder
    {
        public static void AddCss(string path, Page page)
        {
            Literal cssFile = new Literal() { Text = @"<link href=""" + page.ResolveUrl(path) + @""" type=""text/css"" rel=""stylesheet"" />" };
            page.Header.Controls.Add(cssFile);
        }
    }
}
```

**and then through this helper class, all I have to do is :**

```
CssAdder.AddCss("~/Resources/Styles/MainMaster/MainDesign.css", this.Page);
CssAdder.AddCss("~/Resources/Styles/MainMaster/MainLayout.css", this.Page);
CssAdder.AddCss("~/Resources/Styles/Controls/RightMainMenu.css", this.Page);
//...
```

So I can add as much as I want with one line of simple code.

It also works with Masterpage and content page relationships.

Hope it helps.

**P.S:** I don't know the performance difference between this and other solutions but it looks more elegant and easy to consume.

Comment: One gotcha I found: make sure your <head> tag has  runat="server" or the code won't find it.

Comment: And for ***icon***?: `<link href="https://www.viesgo.com/wp-content/uploads/vsg-favicon.png" rel="icon" sizes="32x32">`

Answer (score 5):

I'll paste the thing which worked for me:

```
HtmlLink link = new HtmlLink();
//Add appropriate attributes
link.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
link.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
link.Href = "/Resources/CSS/NewStyles.css";
link.Attributes.Add("media", "screen, projection");
//add it to page head section
this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(link);
```

Even I searched a lot on this, I'd to add a overriding style sheet when a button is clicked. I used the above code and it worked perfectly to me.

Comment: And BTW, i use a masterpage, and the button was in the footer; so as the pasted code.

Answer (score 4):

I define a generic HTML `<link>` and set the href attribute programmatically.

For example, in the page `<head>` I have:

```
<link id="cssStyle" runat="server" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />.
```

Then in Page_Load set the Href property of cssStyle:

```
cssStyle.Href = "path/to/Styles.css";
```

Seems a bit cleaner with the upside of having the design control over placing the `<link>` in the desired order.

Answer (score 2):

I went a step over, I wanted a method that makes me impossible to add include duplicates, something like `ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude()`.
The solution is to give an ID to the control added in the Header section.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Key))
     if (Page.Header.FindControl(Key) != null) return;

HtmlLink link = new HtmlLink();
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Key)) link.ID = Key;
link.Href = StyleUrl; 
link.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css"); 
link.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
Page.Header.Controls.Add(link);
```

For the complete article I wrote: http://www.idea-r.it/Blog.aspx?Article=49