# How to add CSS link file to ASP.NET page header dynamically using C#?

Tags: asp.net, css, c#-3.0

How to add CSS link file to ASP.NET page header dynamically using C#?

I need to change between language by changing CSS style file dynamically. Please help me to do this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think this has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943037/adding-stylesheets-programmatically-in-asp-net

Answer (score 5):

Use `HtmlLink` class to add css dynamically, this is how:

```
protected void Page_Init(...)
{
    HtmlLink myHtmlLink = new HtmlLink();
    myHtmlLink.Href = "~/css1.css";
    myHtmlLink.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
    myHtmlLink.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");

    Page.Header.Controls.Add(myHtmlLink);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> i need to change between language

Consider using resx-files if the elements depend on the selected languages.