# Is there a way to have a user control ensure its page has a certain css file?

Tags: asp.net, webusercontrols

(Please note that I'm not talking about this: [How to make user controls know about css classes in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34390/how-to-make-user-controls-know-about-css-classes-in-asp-net) )

I have some user controls which css styles comes from a small .css file.  I would like to know if there is a way for the user control to tell any page it is placed in that the page needs to import this .css file.

What I'm trying to do is avoid forgetting to add a link to the .css file every time I add a usercontrol to a page by just having the control itself say "Hey, page that contains me, I need you to import this .css file if you haven't already".

Comment: As far as I know, there's no OOB functionality to do that, but you could write your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add the css in programatically from the user control itself. This questions gives a good example how

[Adding StyleSheets Programmatically in Asp.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943037/adding-stylesheets-programmatically-in-asp-net)

Therefore the containing pages don't need to know about the css.

Or i guess you could just add it in the usercontrols in some style tags. Depends on your cascade. That one feels a bit dirty to me - i wouldn't sully myself with such unpleasantness (he lies)

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry it took me so long to mark this as an answer - I got caught up doing another part of the project then testing the answer I used.  I also can't believe I never hit that question while doing my own searches.