# Add css class from code behind using literal control

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I am adding a css class to my aspx page from c# code behind.
here's how I am going around

```
public void OnPreRenderComplete(EventArgs e)
{
  Page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"/Content/Css/Edit.css"+"\" />"));
}
```

The code is working as expected.
Now the thing is that I DO NOT want to use literal control to add the class if possible.
Is there a way around to do the same without using literal control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlGenericControl css;
    css = new HtmlGenericControl();
    css.TagName = "style";
    css.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
    css.InnerHtml = "@import \"/foobar.css\";";
    Page.Header.Controls.Add(css);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Someone already raised this question and this may help you:

```
HtmlLink link = new HtmlLink();
//Add appropriate attributes
link.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
link.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
link.Href = "/Resources/CSS/NewStyles.css";
link.Attributes.Add("media", "screen, projection");
//add it to page head section
this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(link);
```

[Adding StyleSheets Programmatically in Asp.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943037/adding-stylesheets-programmatically-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

```
HtmlLink link = new HtmlLink();
link.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
link.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
link.Href = "/Content/Css/Edit.css";
this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(link);
```