# How to use a variable set at build time in asp files

Tags: asp.net, .net

My application has to use a CDN in production. We don't want to use the same CDN in development and production. How and where can I define a property "CDN_URL" for each build profile so that it is substituted at buid time or retrieved dynamically at runtime.

I'd like to write something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${CDN_URL}/styles/base.css" />
```

Comment: What version of ASP.NET are you using? Web Forms? MVC? Where do you save the property?

Comment: We use .NET Framework 4.5. Today we don't use any property at all and we don't have any constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to store the CDN URL in the app settings in the web.config.

For example:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Live_CDNURL" value="http://live.cdn.com"/>
    <add key="Development_CDNURL" value="http://dev.cdn.com"/>
</appSettings>
```

Then in the application you can use:

```
 WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Live_CDNURL"];
```

Then simply add the stylesheet using asp following something like [Adding StyleSheets Programmatically in Asp.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943037/adding-stylesheets-programmatically-in-asp-net)

Or do:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Live_CDNURL")%>/styles/base.css" />
```

Comment: thanks you explained me how to use a property from web.config in an ASP page. But how can I use a single property "CDNURL" and change its value depending on my deployment platform ?

Comment: Well you can store just CDNURL in the web.config - you will have on web.config used in dev and a separate web.config used in live.